# Разбор строки ввода на части с сопоставлением их со списком возможных команд

Tags: python

Ещё раз привет, как много проблем и все их приходится гуглить.

На этот раз, когда я писал текстовую RPG, мне стало интересно, можно ли написать такую функцию, которая могла бы дробить введённый текст на слова и проверять на совпадение с базовыми действиями (прописанными заранее),  при этом если в тексте есть 2 и более словодействий, то они выполняются по порядку (все).

Типа «произнести чудовищное заклятье и выпить крутое зелье»:

- произнести заклятье
- выпить зелье

Код:

```
sumka=[‘a’,’b’,’c’]
def gdl (a):
for e in range(len(a)):
    if a[e] in ("атака", "атаковать", "ударить"):
        return ('вы атакуете')
    elif a[e] in  ('выпить', 'взять', 'пить', 'глотнуть', 'хлебнуть'):
        return ('вы пьёте')
    elif a[e] in ('сумка', 'портфель', 'рюкзак', 'сумку', 'с'):
        return (sumka)
    else:
        return ('хммм, может по-другому или что ещё')
```

Как бы это сделать, и возможно ли вообще такое?

Comment: Ну мне больше как заставит проверять в определённом порядке

Comment: ``for e in range(len(a))`` и так проверяет в определенном порядке. Кстати, эта строчка - антипаттерн и лучше использовать ``for e in a``.

Comment: И заголовок измените. Тут не семинар по философии.

Comment: Как я понял, нужен "интеллектуальный" разбор командной строки? По похожим токенам или даже грамматически, глаголы, существительные...

Comment: Эм мне бы понять как сделать по очерёдную проверку проще чем я думаю так-как это будет громостко и возможно не правильно а то что вы объясняете я уже и сам написал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По мне это надо делать так:

1. Привести всё к нормальной форме (например все глаголы заменить инфинитивами, существительные именительным падежом и т.д.)
2. Разделить предложение на составные действия (и, или, запятые)
3. И уже к нормальной форме разделённого предложения применять шаблоны конкретных действий.

Если же у Вас вопрос, именно КАК пачку строк сравнить с другой строкой, то, лучше, почитайте про регэкспы.

Comment: А как перевести всё к нормальной форме я таких команд не знаю(

Comment: "А это правильный вопрос" :-) В самом просто приближении, например слова "Атака", "Атаковать", "Ударить" заменять на "Атаковать".  Как заменять слова в тексте знаете?

Comment: Нет с этим ещё не приходилось встречаться в python

Comment: Наверное, можно начать с документации? https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду я ознакомился с данной статьёй но не увидел никого замена слов (

Comment: Может вы могли бы привести пример на python

Comment: `S.replace` - плохо ознакомились :-(

Comment: Но ведь вё равно придётся прописывать все возможные варианты

Comment: @MioMelliot, так в этом то и суть программирования. Не хотите прописывать все возможные варианты, стройте нейросеть или ИИ, чтобы они это делали за Вас :-)

Comment: Ну там просто есть решенье по проше я думал что может что ещё есть